# Mypy can't find obvious type mismatch when using namespace-packages and subfolders with the same name

Tags: python, mypy

The problem is as simple as can be if put in one file:

```
class A():
  a = 1

class B():
  b = 2

def test(x: A):
  return x

def testit():
  b = B()
  test(b)
```

And mypy finds the issue here with `mypy test_folder --check-untyped-defs`

But if those functions / classes are put in various files mypy doesn't detect the problem. It doesn't even warn that it can't piece information together which IMO is the biggest problem.

I spent some time to create a minimal reproducible version:

The file tree looks like this:

```
src
  mb2
    base.py
    steps
      init
        step.py
        impl.py
      jmeter
        step.py
  test
    test.py
```

The content of the 5 involved files is:

base.py

```
class BaseCfg:
    pass
```

test.py

```
from mb2.steps.jmeter.step import JCfg
from mb2.steps.init.impl import get_resource_costs

class TestCollectMetrics:
    def test_get_resource_costs(self):
        cfg = JCfg()
        get_resource_costs(cfg)  # <- Wrong type should be detected
```

init/impl.py

```
from .step import Cfg

def get_resource_costs(config: Cfg):
    pass
```

init/step.py

```
from mb2.base import BaseCfg

class Cfg(BaseCfg):
    pass
```

jmeter/step.py

```
from mb2.base import BaseCfg

class JCfg(BaseCfg):
    pass
```

The test is passing an object of type `JCfg` to the method `get_resource_costs`. While the method specifies it needs type `Cfg`. This doens't get detected by mypy.

It only runs with `--namespace-packages` as otherwise the duplicate `step.py` files become a problem. So the command to reproduce is:

```
mypy src --check-untyped-defs --namespace-packages
```

This returns `Success: no issues found in 5 source files`

putting `reveal_type(cfg)` and `reveal_type(get_resource_costs)` into test.py returns `Revealed type is "Any"`.

Putting local errors in any of the 5 files gets detected, so mypy is checking all files.

I assume it is connected to namespace-packages not being able to resolve paths and silently failing. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I'm also getting errors about missing stubs. What does `reveal_types(cfg)` and `reveal_types(get_resource_costs)` output in `test_get_resource_costs`?

Comment: This does not reproduce. I recreated your tree and did `mypy . --show-error-codes --check-untyped-defs --warn-unused-ignores --namespace-packages --explicit-package-bases` (without `--explicit-package-bases` this fails with `Duplicate module named "step" (also at "./mb2/steps/init/step.py")`, as expected) inside `src` directory. I got the expected error (`Argument 1 to "get_resource_costs" has incompatible type "JCfg"; expected "Cfg"`). Voting to close as not reproducible, please share more details to avoid closure.

Comment: If running mypy outside of `src` (with `mypy src ...`), I'm getting different errors like `Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "mb2.steps.jmeter.step"`, but nothing close to "fails silently".

Comment: Also, what's the reason to avoid adding `__init__.py` and using namespace packages instead? It's usually just a source of trouble, that needs justification (because path manipulation is not really convenient compared to common import machinery). If I add `__init__.py` files, type checking works as expected outside of `src` too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! The call tree had a minor typo which I fixed. I updated mypy to `1.1.1` and was able to reproduce the response `Success: no issues found in 5 source files` with command `mypy src --check-untyped-defs --namespace-packages`. @chepner reveal_type() prints `Revealed type is "Any"`. Whic is what I suspected. But how do I fix it? Or continue to debug it?

Comment: Ah, I missed that I had a local setup.cfg file in the directory. It set `ignore_missing_imports = True`. Still working more on the repro. But I think that may explain most of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the errors were not found were due to `ignore_missing_imports = True` in my `setup.cfg`.

The underlying problem is related to module discovery:

- Mypy is detecting modules differently than python. Which will always be a problem in my opinion
- Mypy can't deal with "Duplicate modules".

Together this makes it hard to properly discover all modules, but only discover them **once**.

In the end I needed to use `MYPYPATH=src mypy src --strict --namespace-packages --explicit-package-bases`.

Setting `MYPYPATH=src` in addition to using `mypy src` is important. Unclear to me why.